# syntax error but coudn't debug javascript prototype

Tags: javascript

```
// create your Animal class here
function Animal(name, numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}


// create the sayName method for Animal
Animal.prototype.sayName(){
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
}

// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

not working, cannot find what's wrong. Any tool to debug besides chrome console? sometime it can't tell which line has problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create prototype methods like this

```
Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// create your Animal class here
function Animal(name, numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}


Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
}

var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```